# Identify a novel about a viral epidemic

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering, apocalypse

I read this at least 10 years ago and I do not remember it being very new.  So it is possibly older than that.

The protagonist is a scientist working in a genetics related field. The book deals with an epidemic spreading across the world slowly pushing towards and end of the world / zombie apocalypse type situation.

Two things I distinctly remember:

1) One of the early symptoms of the disease is loss of inhibition. There is mention of a colleague of the protagonist who flashes him in the shower area. Also the protagonist's wife, who is a painter, starts painting more risque pictures before turning macabre.

2) There is a short DNA segment which the protagonist keeps remembering like a tune stuck in his mind throughout the novel. This piece of DNA turns out to be key to a cure at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If the epidemic lowers people's intelligence, it could be [IQ 83](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0595276091), (1978), by Arthur Herzog.  I think I recall it having both of the events you remember.

> YOU ARE DR. JAMES HEALEY AND LAST WEEK YOU WERE A GENIUS That was
>   before the DNA experiments. Before the accident you said could never
>   happen… Since then you have felt your mind decaying a little more each
>   day. You have watched your wife slip into imbecility. You have seen
>   the crowds growing murderous with animal terror, the President of the
>   United States babbling and drooling on TV… Only one thing separates
>   you from them. You, at least, know what is happening as you search for
>   the cure for the horror you have unleashed upon the world—as each day
>   the dimming of your mind lowers your chance of finding it!